# Debugging my App not returning the correct local variables

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

My current application first launcher is a broadcast receiver. It does have activities but they are not the first launcher. In order for me to debug it, I use the method `debuggable true` in my Gradle and I put breakpoints where I want to debug.

Debugging is working totally fine. The only bummer is that when I'm in debug mode on my IDE, my variables are showing me some variables that are totally unrelated to the local variables that I have in the class that I'm debugging. (Image Below)

[image]

For instance, my class `FirstLaunchTaskWorker` is not showing me any of the local variables that it has.

**Any ideas how I can get my class local variables to show?**

Comment: are you using thread or something like that (multi task programming)?

Comment: @pooyan you mean like android/java multi-threading?

Comment: yes. I mean multi threading.

Comment: @pooyan Yes I am. How is that relevant to the current question?

Comment: I don't no about your code but i think it is possible that when you are debugging your code you forget to think about the thread that you are in it. you should be consider about your thread specially if the bunch of code that you are debugging it ,is running inside a thread.(it was just a guess because i don't no about your code.)

Comment: @pooyan so I browsed through the different threads that I'm running asynchronously, and the image that I captured is actually a list of variables from the correct worker thread, which is workerHandlerThread: FirstLaunchTaskWorker.